# Ruby on Rails: Rake related any command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, rake

I tried to upgrade an existing project from Ruby 2.3 to Ruby 2.6 (the latest). Everything was working fine until I received the following error on running `rake db:create`

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity
/home/user/application/blogs/activity_extension.rb:10:in <module:Application>'
/home/user/application/blogs/activity_extension.rb:1:in'
/home/user/application/blogs/project.rb:8:in <top (required)>'
/home/user/application/users.rb:1:inrequire'
/home/user/application/users.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
/home/user/application/Rakefile:4:in'
```

I've checked the database.yml and everything seems to be fine. Here is the database.yml file -

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    username: -------
    password: -------
    host: localhost
    port: 5432
    pool: 5

development:
    <<: *default
    database: mydbName
```

Is anyone having any idea that why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you try without port number? I tried for Ruby 2.7 yesterday and it was working fine.

Comment: It looks like the indentation of your YAML file is incorrect. Can you please check that?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Sorry, but it is not working even without the port number.

Comment: @spickermann Yes I've checked the indentation and it is in the correct format. It is showing the incorrect format here because I've copied the code from file. Otherwise in my database.yml file the format is fine.

Comment: Your path structure is a bit unusual for a Ruby on Rails project (no `app` or `lib` folder). What version of Rails do you use? Plus the namespacing (`PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity`) is unexpected too. Do you use a special gem or do you have some extra configuration for auto-loading files?

Comment: I'm using the rails version 4.2 and no I'm not using any extra configuration for auto-loading files.